# Policy for using SIM's credit in iOS / Android apps

Tags: android, ios, billing

I am creating an iOS application for a telco operator. I want to charge the customer's credit from his SIM (network services provider billing account). For subscribing/unsubscribing the services provided by the operator, i am calling a web service which implicitly charges the customer credit from his SIM's billing account.

Is there any Apple or Android policy which disallows this kind of billing process so they may reject my app from going to the app store ?

Comment: What are you selling? Services/apps/physical goods...?

Comment: Services provided by the network operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For publishing on [Google Play](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), it would seem you're safe;

> In-app purchases: Developers offering additional content, services or
> functionality within an application downloaded from Google Play must
> use Google Play's payment system as the method of payment, except:
>
> ...
>
> - where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the application itself (e.g. buying songs that can be
>   played on other music players)

The latter would seem to apply to you as long as you're not selling in-app content, but you should read the conditions yourself with the extra info you have about the application in mind.